# Undefined CLSID_PropertyChangeArray

Tags: c++, winapi

While attempting to compile a C++ project, I have received errors related to the definition of `CLSID_PropertyChangeArray`, which is [listed on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775223(v=vs.85).aspx). I have imported the required header file of `Propsys.h`, but the problem remains. I continue to receive messages like the following:

```
propsys.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CLSID_PropertyChangeArray


propsys.cpp(610): error C2065: 'CLSID_PropertyChangeArray': undeclared identifier
```

Am I doing this wrong? I'm not that familiar with win32 c++, so is this a novice mistake?

Comment: There is a big difference between *undefined* and *unresolved* symbols. The first is a compiler error, the second is a linker error. You are experiencing the second. A `CLSID` is a `struct` containing multiple integers. The `.h` file declares an `extern` statement for the `CLSID_PropertyChangeArray` variable (ie `extern const CLSID CLSID_PropertyChangeArray;`), but you need to add a `.lib` file to your project that defines the actual `CLSID_PropertyChangeArray` variable, or else define it directly in your code (ie `const CLSID CLSID_PropertyChangeArray = {...};`), so the linker can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

really this is bug in documentation I sure. `CLSID_PropertyChangeArray` or `PropertyChangeArray` not defined in any SDK or WDK headers. only one way get [`IPropertyChangeArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775223(v=vs.85).aspx) interface call [`PSCreatePropertyChangeArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776491(v=vs.85).aspx)

---

if fast look for [`PSCreatePropertyChangeArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776491(v=vs.85).aspx) - here exist symbol `CLSID_PropertyChangeArray` ( `{8b6a3ebb-cd13-4704-93c5-bc3413104e4c}`) but this function not call `CoCreateInstance` with it, but use internal  implementation. also this class even not registered - so attempt call  `CoCreateInstance` for `{8b6a3ebb-cd13-4704-93c5-bc3413104e4c}` return `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` error

[image]

Comment: @xaav - if you have *undefined* symbol - the best solution do search in some file manager in `SDK` (or `WDK`, `VC`) *include directories*. if this symbol correct and defined - you found `.h` where it placed - and need include this `.h` file. if you have *unresolved* symbols - also do search but this time in *LIB* folders. this say you from where this symbol exported (if it must be exported) and which `.lib` need include as *linker* input. simply enough rules but very helpful